# Grip diameter of a riser bar?

Tags: handlebars, brake-levers, grips

I bought a riser bar ([Easton EA30](https://www.eastoncycling.com/products/details/ea30-riser-bar)) and I want to buy grips and brake levers to put on it. I know the clamp diameter is 31.8mm, but how do I figure out the bar end diameter? I don't have a caliper to measure it and it's not written anywhere (box, instructions manual, ...).

As suggested by one of the answer, the grip size is likely going to be 22.2 What makes me not sure is the fact that Easton (the same manifacturer of the bar) only sells grips of size 30 and 33 (Ref: https://www.eastoncycling.com/products/details/lock-on-grips)

Comment: Do you still have parts from your old bike, such as brake levers? You might simply try if they fit.

Comment: @gschenk that would be easy :) It's a new bike that I am building, so all components are new, including grips and levres, which I still have to order.

Comment: Yes, as other have said all MTB bars will have a grip area with a 22.2mm diameter. Any diameter listed when looking at grips to purchase will be the outside diameter of the grip surface. this is thankfully one thing they have yet to "optimize"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Sheldon Brown's handlebar reference](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-handlebars.html). It lists typical clamp and outer bar diameters.

Unfortunately it does not contain oversized mountain bike handlebars, like your 31.8 mm riser bar. I suspect that the typical diameter for mountain bike bars at the handles at the grips is still 22.2 mm. You may see in the table that while the clamp diameter changed often, the outer diameter stayed constant at 22.2 mm and 23.8, respectively, for mountain bikes and road bikes.

Comment: Yep, all MTB bars, even the new 'over sized oversize' 35.0mm is still 22.2 for clamp. Its a wonder with the manufacturers changing standard fast then I change underwear. A new clamp diameter would mean new shifters, brakes, remotes, grips - there is pot of gold at the end of that standards change.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it's a pity there is not a row for oversized mtb bars. I believe it's because they are new?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the 30 and 33mm sizes are the "outside" diameter of the grips (the diameter where your hands are actually grabbing) made to match either small or large hands (or just personal preference). The inside diameter should still be 22.2.